# Converting a .csv.gz to .csv in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, gzip

I have read the documentation and a few additional posts on SO and other various places, but I can't quite figure out this concept:

When you call `csvFilename = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')` then `reader = csv.reader(open(csvFilename))`, is that `reader` not a valid csv file?

I am trying to solve the problem outlined below, and am getting a `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, GzipFile found` error on line 41 and 7 (highlighted below), leading me to believe that the gzip.open and csv.reader do not work as I had previously thought.

**Problem I am trying to solve**

I am trying to take a `results.csv.gz` and convert it to a `results.csv` so that I can turn the `results.csv` into a python dictionary and then combine it with another python dictionary.

File 1:

```
alertFile = payload.get('results_file')
alertDataCSV = rh.dataToDict(alertFile) # LINE 41
alertDataTotal = rh.mergeTwoDicts(splunkParams, alertDataCSV)
```

Calls File 2:

```
import gzip
import csv

def dataToDict(filename):
    csvFilename = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(open(csvFilename)) # LINE 7
    alertData={}
    for row in reader:
        alertData[row[0]]=row[1:]
    return alertData

def mergeTwoDicts(dictA, dictB):
    dictC = dictA.copy()
    dictC.update(dictB)
    return dictC
```

*edit: also forgive my non-PEP style of naming in Python

Comment: Btw, if you're not using the whole dict you may use `ChainMap` and save the copying

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I believe ChainMap is a Python 3 feature, which sadly I am unable to use on this particular project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gzip.open` returns a file-like object (same as what plain `open` returns), not the name of the decompressed file. Simply pass the result *directly* to `csv.reader` and it will work (the `csv.reader` will receive the decompressed lines). `csv` does expect text though, so on Python 3 you need to open it to read as text (on Python 2 `'rb'` is fine, the module doesn't deal with encodings, but then, neither does the `csv` module). Simply change:

```
csvFilename = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(open(csvFilename))
```

to:

```
# Python 2
csvFile = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(csvFile)  # No reopening involved

# Python 3
csvFile = gzip.open(filename, 'rt', newline='')  # Open in text mode, not binary, no line ending translation
reader = csv.reader(csvFile)  # No reopening involved
```

Comment: Note: If the file encoding might not match your locale encoding, make sure to pass `encoding='utf-8'` (or `'latin-1'`, or `utf-16'` or whatever the file's encoding really is) to `gzip.open` to make sure it is decoding correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much, I felt stupid asking but I had already wasted so much time trying to figure out what was wrong. (and yes, my naming conventions suck)

Comment: Just realized the question is for Python 2, so I've made a few more updates to address both.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me for `python==3.7.9`:

```
import gzip

my_filename = my_compressed_file.csv.gz

with gzip.open(my_filename, 'rt') as gz_file:
    data = gz_file.read() # read decompressed data
    with open(my_filename[:-3], 'wt') as out_file:
         out_file.write(data) # write decompressed data
```

my_filename[:-3] is to get the actual filename so that it does get a random filename.